# C# Treeview Update from Background Worker

Tags: c#, linq, treeview, backgroundworker

I am working on Files Counting... While I am Scanning a Directory in Background, I must select that corresponding node which has same Name as the Directory Name in my `TreeView` via `ProgressChanged` handler.

Treeview was already populated with all sub directories with specified root Path..

My `ProgressChanged` Event will be fired 1 time per 15 milliseconds.. (so Fast isn't it).

so , when i update my treeview in that handler , my window is Freezed, and so slow... and even Not responding...

**Question:**

how to update UI s in fast running `ProgressChanged` handler..

**Code**

```
var nodes = tv.FlattenTree()
            .Where(n => n.Text == new FileInfo(CurrentFilePath).Directory.Parent.Name)
            .ToList();
```

by above code I am selecting the Node.

```
if (nodes.Count() > 0)
{
    nodes[0].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    nodes[0].EnsureVisible();
}
```

by above code I am updating the treeview...

Comment: Don't update that fast? Perform bigger updates at lower intervals. I would also remove the `EnsureVisible`, as it may be undesired UX to move things around on the screen while the user is looking at it.

Comment: Yea.... have to plan it.. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the task is updating at an incredible pace and updating the UI is fairly expensive. Why don't you update only every tenth tick? You can also disable painting while thee TreeView is being populated - as adding nodes onmass while the UI is active will hurt performance.

Comment: Yea .. its Expensive rite??? Yep.. I can pause the Update.. and let the operation as it is.. I can update it.. for every 3 seconds... UUUHHHHHHH ... great...